# need to add alert before defining variable

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on a project but I encountered a problem:

This was my initial code

```
getID_Q(); //defines the content of div#id_q
var id_q = document.getElementById("id_q").innerHTML;
```

But it seems that my var won't be defined unless I add an alert() between the two lines. 
Like this:

```
getID_Q();
alert('random text');
var id_q = document.getElementById("id_q").innerHTML;
```

I don't understand how adding this alert() would help the rest of the code...

Comment: Maybe you need an `onLoad` to wait until the document is ready.

Comment: Probably the `getID_Q()` function is asynchronous, and since `alert()` call halts JavaScript execution, the rest of the code is executed after `getID_Q()` ended.